# Query listing the name, surname and salary information of the employees with the highest salary in each unit. (With a single query)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Table 1

```
 drop table Department
    create table  Department (
        dep_id int primary key not null,
        dep_name char(50)
    )
```

Table 2

```
create table Employee (
    emp_id int primary key not null,
    name char(50),
    surname char(50),
    salary int ,
    emp_dep_id int references Department(dep_id) not null
    )
```

**Adding data**:

```
insert into Department values
        ('1','A'),
        ('2','B'),
        ('3','C')

insert into Employee values 
    ('1','Susan','James','100000','1'),
    ('2','Steve','Jones','80000','1'),
    ('3','John','Connors','300000','2'),
    ('4','Adrian','Ball','500000','3'),
    ('5','Amy','Smith','500000','3'),
    ('6','Jane','Smith','200000','2'),
    ('7','June','Smyth','75000','1'),
    ('8','Jill','Hanlon','90000','3')
```

How can I get the name, surname, and salary information of the employees with the highest salary in each department? (With a single query).

I want a table like below.

```
name                  surname                  salary 
Susan                 James                    100000
John                  Connors                  300000
Andrian               Ball                     500000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. You use the partition split up the departments, sort by the salary, and then insert the data to a temp table. Then just grab the top one from each group.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_dep_id ORDER BY salary DESC) [RowNum],
    Name,
    Surname,
    Salary
INTO #tempValues
FROM
    employe

SELECT * FROM #tempValues WHERE RowNum = 1

DROP TABLE #tempValues
```

If you don't want to use a temp table, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    X.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_dep_id ORDER BY salary DESC) [RowNum],
        Name,
        Surname,
        Salary
    FROM
        employe
) AS X
WHERE
    X.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished using `window functions`, assign a sequence to each group and order by the salary, then filter:

```
select name, surname, salary from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by emp_dep_id order by salary desc) rn
    from employee
)e
where rn=1
```

Question response.

I can think of a number of ways to get the same results, all however require some correlation between all rows and those with the max salary, and correlation (whether a subquery or cross apply) requires use of `select`.

Your question title states only one *query*, which this is; for example, you could use a temporary table for intermediate results and select from that, in which case that would definitely be two queries - however I can't see how the above could fail to meet the criteria of being a single query, it's about as terse and succinct as you could get.

We are always learning however, so if you do find a solution, please post it here - I would be genuinely curious!

Comment: Is there any option to get exactly the same solution with only one select operation? Because I have to use select only one time. My teacher wants as I mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: @mrProgrammer I started to reply with a comment but ran out of room, so have added into answer above!